# Problemas com o uso do ui-route AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Estou usando SPA utilizo AngularJS e UI-ROUTE

Desejo ao clicar num item de menu escrever o item selecionado numa barra que fica no header e não no ui-view. Consigo atribuir o valor a uma variável de $scope do controller mas não ocorre a ataulização na página

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlHome">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <ul >

  <li >
  <a ui-sref="home" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">Home </a>
  </li>

  <li >
  <a ui-sref="pedido" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">Pedido</a>
  </li>

  </ul>

</div>

<div>
  <p>Item Selecionado: {{pagina}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Seria benéfico também incluir esse código na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Mova o header para dentro da *view*, ou compartilhe o item carregado na *view* com o header - via serviço, por exemplo, ou (não recomendado) `$rootScope`.

(Poste seu código. Assim poderemos sugerir implementações baseadas nele.)